# django rest - данные не предоставлены

Tags: django, http, rest, https

Доброе время суток.

О сайте:
В связи с некоторыми обстоятельствами он должен работать как на http так и https.
На сайте есть голосовалка, которая берет пользователя из запроса `request.user`

Проблема:
При голосовании с http версии сайта, прихотит ответ `403 Учетные данные не были предоставлены`.
При голосовании с https все нормально

Как решить проблему? Мучаюсь 2 часа с этим вопросом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запрос с http должен был идти на http а не на https
Вопрос решен